# Is it legal to run Xcode on OS X Lion Server in a virtualized environment in Windows?

Tags: macos

Just wondering if it's legal to run Xcode on OS X Lion Server in a virtualized environment on Windows? I know it's not for the client but I've heard that it's legal with the server. It this true?

Comment: IIRC Somewhere in the EULA says that it must only run on Mac hardware

Comment: OS X Lion Server is just a suite of apps installed on top of the Client version, so you're bound by both EULAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if you boot Windows on authentic Apple Mac hardware?

Answer (score 3):

No. The [EULA for Mac OS X Lion Server](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosxserver107.pdf) says:

> 2 . Permitted License Uses and Restrictions.
>   A. Standard and Preinstalled Apple Software License. Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, unless you obtained the Apple Software from the Mac App Store or under a volume license, maintenance or other written agreement from Apple, you are granted a limited, non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) **copy of the Apple Software on a single Apple-branded computer at any one time.** For example, these standard, single-copy license terms apply to you if you obtained the Apple Software preinstalled on Apple- branded hardware.

which means you can't install it on non Apple-branded hardware (but it might be legal if you virtualize using Apple hardware on Windows)